# Can't get url by file_get_contents, but in browser it's works

Tags: php, http, curl, web

I get url in json, and try `file_get_contents($url)`, but i have 404 error. If I just copy url in chrome I get 200OK and content. If I copy url to new var - it's works, but in var_dump i see that's same url(signatute is dynamic)

```
    $resp = json_decode($resp);

    $str1 = 'http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/50c1a501266c4e8082ee6c03fc604d8a?Signature=FzYwSIhkGrYxQpmygbkFuXibwa4%3D&Expires=1434359105&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ';
    $str2 = $resp->result_url;


    var_dump($str1);
    var_dump($str2);

    echo "\n\n";

    echo file_get_contents($str1);
    echo "\n\n";
    echo file_get_contents($str2);

    exit;
```

I need run file_get_contents from json var...

Comment: I get `access denied` - `Message has expired`. Could be that you'd have to auth to the service to actually access the resources? Anyway I can't reproduce a 200 on the provided url.

Comment: Sorry that's live link - `http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/8bc05c29ddd7439d8097bebbfd584535?Signature=BYtkjP6x3SJZ%2Ffdo42JsCfNsg50%3D&Expires=1434363361&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ`

Comment: Now i'm getting `Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters` as a message. Still would guess your browser saved the auth (`http basic` maybe?) but your php's requests are stateless and there's no auth attached to your requests.

Comment: please try this - `http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/a2647d2323c04e02a188526ced71847d?Signature=TZp8wQdLOpOVShd3Uyx56td4gqE%3D&Expires=1434364401&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ`

Comment: `curl http://ajillion-customer-files.s3.amazonaws.com/reports/a2647d2323c04e02a188526ced71847d\?Signature\=TZp8wQdLOpOVShd3Uyx56td4gqE%3D\&Expires\=1434364401\&AWSAccessKeyId\=AKIAJ35DX3F5NPKSAKMQ`
`{"rows": [{"advertiser": "BM Fogzy", "hits": 0, "campaign": "BM Fozgy US (87417)", "revenue": 4.049, "source": 4, "impressions": 16196}]}`

Comment: if copy from console i have backslashes, why?